# failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x5

Tags: program, anchor-spl, sendtransactionerror

I encountered an error while executing a program call. Specifically, the error arises during the invocation of a function where I'm attempting to create a metadata account using the create_metadata_account_v3 method of spl_token::metadata. I think that the error is from this method call.

Here's the method call

```
let seeds = &["mint".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];

        // CPI Context

        create_metadata_accounts_v3(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                    metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(), // the metadata account being created
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(), // the mint account of the metadata account
                    mint_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(), // the mint authority of the mint account
                    update_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(), // the update authority of the metadata account
                    payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(), // the payer for creating the metadata account
                    system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), // the system program account
                    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(), // the rent sysvar account
                },
                &[&seeds[..]],
            ), // cpi context
            data_v2, // token metadata
            true,    // is_mutable
            true,    // update_authority_is_signer
            None,    // collection details
        )?;
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions or insights on resolving this issue

Answer (score 2):

If this is an error comming from the `token_metadata_program` then my way is to search for the program and checking the error set.

For that the metadata program can be found at
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata

and the errors are at
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/token-metadata%40v1.13.3/programs/token-metadata/program/src/error.rs#L34

From the description it seems to be a wrong seed used for metadata creation.
What is the seed you used for `mint` account creation and does it align with the `"mint".as_bytes()` as it's in the code at `let seeds`?